# Android Studio Auto Generated public final class R file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Much appreciate that someone could help me.

My project works fine last night, then this suddenly happen.. all my tags and widgets gone and android suddenly generate this R class file

```
below is what i have tried and nothing helps
 1. Invalidate Caches/Restart...
 2. Rebuild Project
 3. Clean Project
 4. Restart Android Studio
 5. Reinstall Android Studio
```

Check Box Java Class
[image: Check Box Java Class]
Check Box XML
[image: Check Box xml]
Toggle Java Class
[image: Toggle Java Class]
Toggle XML
[image: Toggle XML]

Comment: This does not look good. I hope you are using a version control system for your code.

Comment: R file is a generated file, no need worry about that, Sync your project once and rebuild project, post the logs here. we can identify what went wrong.

Comment: @roronoa_zoro did you recognize that the source files shown in the screenshots contain what seems to be some project configuration? Definitely not Java or Layout xml.

Comment: @Henry yes, its seems like building some sort of library application, or something. also there are multiple usage of `<application>` tags in xml, doesn't give a clear picture of purpose of the app.

Comment: anyone solved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is back to normal once i removed those 2 classes.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

This kept happening to me in Android Studio 3.2.1. 
I updated to Android Studio 3.3 RC (Beta Channel) and the problem seems to be gone.

**-- Edited/Updated --**

I regret posting that 3.3 solved this issue. It didn't.
This keeps happening with my project, even in 3.3